# How to automatically linebreak a (small) inline math formula?

Tags: math-mode, paragraphs

I often use small inline math notation such as `$\FuncName(a)$` in paragraphs. These math expressions are smaller than some words, so I think it's fine to inline them instead of putting them on their own line with something like double $$.

But LaTeX will allow these short math notations to hang over the edge of a justified paragraph. I don't like this.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\FuncName}{\mathsf{FuncName}}
\begin{document}
Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, esollicitudin vel, ewisi. $\FuncName(a)$
Culpa vitae magnam quis quidem. Tempora quis vitae in odio eligendi ea ea. Qui non cumque velit. Non et quis rerum voluptate. Dignissimos consequuntur impedit aut at explicabo dolor. Reiciendis a fuga et blanditiis et impedit architecto
\end{document}
```

[image: Here's that code compiled]

As you can see, the inline math is outside of the box for the paragraph. I'd like LaTeX to simple put the inline math on the next line. I'd also accept another solution where the paragraph looks nice, but I really don't want to have to do any positioning manually or put the math on its own line.

My question is really similar to this question ([How to automatically linebreak an inline math formula?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/555544/how-to-automatically-linebreak-an-inline-math-formula)) but the solution in that question was to split up the inline math into text mode pieces, which I can't do in my case.

Here's another example where I would want a line break inside the math mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, esollicitudin vel, ewisi. $\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$
Culpa vitae magnam quis quidem. Tempora quis vitae in odio eligendi ea ea. Qui non cumque velit. Non et quis rerum voluptate. Dignissimos consequuntur impedit aut at explicabo dolor. Reiciendis a fuga et blanditiis et impedit architecto
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you allow shorter lines why not use `\raggedright`?

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke I want the text to be justified.

Answer (score 3):

This is not really related to math mode, you will see the same with any non-hyphenatable text. To allow this to be inline without changing the surrounding words to fit, you need to allow white space to stretch more. The simplest way to do that is to use `\sloppy`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\sloppy
Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, esollicitudin vel, ewisi. $\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$
Culpa vitae magnam quis quidem. Tempora quis vitae in odio eligendi ea ea. Qui non cumque velit. Non et quis rerum voluptate. Dignissimos consequuntur impedit aut at explicabo dolor. Reiciendis a fuga et blanditiis et impedit architecto
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\slippy`ness is sometimes necessary, but please don't inflict it on an entire document.  Apply `sloppypar` to only those paragraphs that need it, even though that can't really be done until the text is reasonably final.

Comment: @barbarabeeton well sure and in practice, I'd probably use a less sloppy sloppy perhaps just fiddling wih `\emergncystretch` but just establishing the general principle that to break the lines wihout changing the text you have to give something up, most likely a constraint on how much space can stretch.

Comment: thanks @DavidCarlisle, I've been using ```\sloppy``` for a bit now and started realizing that I want my equations to line-break in more locations without having to manually line-break them myself. For example, the ```\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}``` would make the first line look better if it were line-broken between the ```b``` and ```c```. Is there maybe a way to define my own rules on where a math equation should be line-broken?

Comment: you would need to define `,` as math active (like `'`) and define it to do `,\linebreak[0]` so that it allows line breaks (or simpler use a command like `\mycomma` instead of `,` defined by `\newcommand\mycomma{,\linebreak[0]}` @Grifball